# Knockout observable array get overided when assigning

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

I have an observable array such as

```
obArray=observableArray([]);
```

and then somewhere in down the road, I get the data and assign it to obArray

```
obArray=dataArray;
```

But this one would turn obArray to normal Array (pointing to dataArray in memory). What would be the solution for this usecase for obArray to have same data as dataArray and still remain an observable?

Comment: obArray(dataArray);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put new value into observable array:

```
obArray(dataArray);
```